# How to create cliend-side SSL certificate?

Tags: ssl-certificate

Sorry, I am pretty noob to Digital Certificates.

Basically there is a website, which every time I reach it as `https://ip/`, It throws me an error saying: `Certificate Error: Sorry but you need to provide a client certificate to continue` while I did my research I found this article: https://medium.com/@sevcsik/authentication-using-https-client-certificates-3c9d270e8326

Since I don't have access to website's CA, I assume I have the option of bob only to make the site respond to me as a trusted user.

So I did below:

```
$ openssl req -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout bob_key.pem -out bob_csr.pem -nodes -days 365 -subj "/CN=Alice"

$ openssl x509 -req -in bob_csr.pem -signkey bob_key.pem -out bob_cert.pem -days 365
Enter Export Password: 1234

$ curl --insecure --cert bob.p12 --cert-type p12 https://IP/
```

I also tried: `curl --insecure --cert bob.p12:1234 --cert-type p12 https://IP/`

But I still am getting error from site asking to provide a `client certificate to continue`

Any help? I am in kali-linux env